# How to access Orbeon features HTTP Services, Database Services and Actions after getting the Orbeon 90 Days Professional licences

Tags: orbeon

Can someone help me to access the **orbeon professsional features** such as HTTP Services, Database Services and Actions after getting the Orbeon 90 Days Professional licences

I have placed the licence file in this path
"resources/config/licence.xml"

I have also tried restarting the Tomcat Server but still unable to access.

Please advice
Dev

Comment: Did you follow the steps [here](http://doc.orbeon.com/installation/index.html#license-installation-orbeon-forms-pe-only)?

Answer (score 0):

Download professional edition from https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/releases/download/tag-release-2016.1-ce/orbeon-2016.1.201604200638-PE.zip. Then copy the licence.xml file to ../apache...../webapps/orbeon/